# How to define a local type in XSD?

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation, xml-validation

How to define `type` inside the element in XML Schema rather than referencing in the element?

```
 <xs:element name="Payment" type="my:Payment"/>
```

But I want to do something like below...

```
<xs:element name="Payment">
  <type="my:Payment"/>
</element>
```

But getting syntax error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In XSD, you can reference a *globally-defined*<sup>1</sup> type  as you show in your first example,

```
<xs:element name="Payment" type="my:Payment"/>
```

or use a *locally-defined*, anonymous type, not like you show,

```
<xs:element name="Payment">
  <type="my:Payment"/>
</element>
```

but rather, for example,

```
<xs:element name="Payment">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="Amount"/>
      <xs:element name="Date"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</element>
```

Note that such locally defined types are anonymous and cannot be reused.

**See also**

- [XSD design patterns](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35950540/290085)
- [Denormalize XSD](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25605281/290085)

---

<sup>1</sup> See [How to reference global types in XSD?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42421169/290085) for a detailed example using namespaces.