# How to best use an XSD file to store common definitions for multiple schemas

Tags: xml, xsd, xmlschema

I have multiple XML Schemas that have common definitions. I would like to store those definitions in a common file we'll call it `Common.xsd`. I have the type `guid` referenced in my other schemas successfully already.

I don't need, nor want a file type `.common` to exist however. I haven't yet been able to find a means, such as an attribute, to ensure this isn't allowed and that anything defined in `Common.xsd` is merely there to be inherited from.

**Sample**

`Common.xsd`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema
    targetNamespace="MyAssembly:Core:IO:Schemas"
    elementFormDefault="qualified"
    xmlns="MyAssembly:Core:IO:Schemas"
    xmlns:mstns="MyAssembly:Core:IO:Schemas"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

  <xs:simpleType name="guid">
    <xs:annotation>
      <xs:documentation xml:lang="en-us">
        The representation of a GUID, generally the id of an element.
      </xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:pattern value="\{[a-fA-F0-9]{8}-[a-fA-F0-9]{4}-[a-fA-F0-9]{4}-[a-fA-F0-9]{4}-[a-fA-F0-9]{12}\}"/>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>

</xs:schema>
```

I was hoping that this would be as simple as it is in the case of declaring types within a schema. Basically what I'm talking about here would be an abstract schema for instance:

```xml
<xs:schema abstract="true">

</xs:schema>
```

To clarify I **do** understand that this is not how it works but I'm looking for the closest way to ensure that a `.commmon` file is not allowed or being declared.

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "I don't need, nor want a file type .common to exist however."  Are you trying to prevent `Common.xsd` from being imported multiple times (such as [C++ #include guards](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8020113/290085) are used to prevent with C++ headers)?  You generally do not have to worry about that.

Comment: Do you have an example where [`xsd:include` and `xsd:import`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2357943/290085) are not working for you?

Comment: Okay I'll try to clarify a little better. I'm using the file common.xsd as described. `xsd:include` and `xsd:import` are working just fine elsewhere. I'm not preventing it from being imported multiple times. Importing it multiple times is why it exists so I can store many definitions such as guid as you see there in various other schemas. I'm basically using the file `common.xsd` as an abstract base class.

Comment: What I'm trying to do is prevent this schema from being used to make a `.common` file. If that is attempted I want it to not be allowed if possible, somewhat like a throwing an exception scenario. Is that at all possible? This is fairly new territory for me.

Comment: What is a `.common` file?  Such a file is neither defined in XML / XSD nor implied by either standard.

Comment: Nothing at all. I don't want that to exist but I still want to use a schema to store definitions common across various other schemas in the same project so I don't have to re-write them. `Guid` is a good example. I have several different file schemas that I want to use the `guid` definition in. So rather than putting that `guid` definition in say 4 different schema files I put it in one file called `common.xsd` instead. That all works great I don't have to rewrite `guid` 4 times and that's all great but I feel as though I'm using xsd a little improper here.

Comment: Reason being is that you could technically declare a `.common` file which is illogical in this scenario and I don't want that to be allowed. Does that even matter. If say, someone develops an extension for this software and uses `.common` files it would almost certainly cause issues in various places in my applications the schemas are used for. I hope that clarifies it a little better.

Comment: XSD has nothing to do with file declarations.   Your concerns remain unclear.

Comment: So that leads me to that bottom part there where I proposed the concept of an abstract schema. Just like a class or `complexType` declaration an abstract schema cannot be instantiated it just serves as a container for common definitions to be stored for its inheritors.

Comment: Well that's unfortunate that it didn't clear it up for you. I'm trying really hard here I don't quite get what you're confused about here either.

Comment: You are talking about xml schemas right? https://www.w3schools.com/XML/schema_howto.asp

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231829/discussion-between-kjhughes-and-hawkeye4040).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don't need, nor want a file type .common to exist however.

XSD has no concept of control over file types or file creation.

---

Your plan to group commonly used types into a `Common.xsd` file is sound.

To limit the root elements of valid XML documents, limit the globally defined elements in the XSD; locally defined elements will not be allowed to be used as the root element.

### See also

- [XSD design patterns](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35950540/290085)
- [What's the difference between xsd:include and xsd:import?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2357943/290085)
- [How to reference a local XML Schema file correctly?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19253402/290085)